# SQL Server Stored Procedure Task

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run a stored procedure on a scheduled task on our server. The stored procedure runs a query and gives our stock on hand totals for our stock program.

I have setup the task to run sqlcmd.exe and passed through the below query as a variable in a .sql file. The thing is I'm not 100% sure I am passing through the correct variables though as I am getting an error from SQL.

Below is the task that the server runs when calculating the stock on hand.

```
(@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 bit,@P4 bit,@P5 bit)
declare @SessionID int
declare @Res int
exec @Res = stk_CompileStockOnHandOnDate
'2079-06-01',
null,
@P1,
@P2,
1,
@P3,
@P4,
@P5,
@SessionID out
select @Res Result, @SessionID SessionID
```

The error message I get in SQLCMD is

```
Msg 1050, Level 15, State 1, Server SERVER\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
This syntax is only allowed for parameterized queries.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Server SERVER\SQLEXPRESS, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@P1".
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out what was happening, I needed to modify the query that i was passing through to relect the correct parameters (most of which were null)

Here is the complete query for anyone who has trouble with stored procedures like me!

```
USE [DATABASENAME]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @SessionID int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[stk_CompileStockOnHandOnDate]
        @OnDate = '2079-06-01',
        @InSessionID = NULL,
        @ProductTagID = NULL,
        @StockLocationTagID = NULL,
        @ExtendedInformation = 1,
        @UnitCostReplacement = NULL,
        @UnitCostAVCO = NULL,
        @UnitCostFIFO = NULL,
        @SessionID = @SessionID OUTPUT

SELECT  @SessionID as N'@SessionID'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```